# How to mock a DNS request? (miekg/dns)

Tags: testing, go

I have this small piece of code to explain the codebase I'm trying to test. I've skipped checking errors to make the question short.

```
func lastCNAME(domain string) (lastCNAME string) {
        ns := "8.8.8.8:53"

        c := dns.Client{}
        m := dns.Msg{}
        m.SetQuestion(domain, dns.TypeA)
        r, _, _ := c.Exchange(&m, ns)
        // Last CNAME
        for _, ans := range r.Answer {
                cname, ok := ans.(*dns.CNAME)
                if ok {
                        lastCNAME = cname.Target
                }
        }
        return lastCNAME
}
```

What is the best way to mock the dns query to the nameserver `8.8.8.8`?

[Here is the full code in case anyone's curious.](https://play.golang.org/p/mDaqTNnAll)

Answer (score 1):

You could create an interface for the func in question and provide a stubbed implementation in testing:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/miekg/dns"
)

type LastCnamer interface {
    LastCname(domain string) (lastCname string, err error)
}

type LastCnameResolver string

func (l LastCnameResolver) LastCname(domain string) (lastCname string, err error) {
    ns := string(l)

    c := dns.Client{}
    m := dns.Msg{}
    m.SetQuestion(domain, dns.TypeA)
    r, _, err := c.Exchange(&m, ns)
    if err != nil {
        return lastCname, err
    }
    // Last CNAME
    for _, ans := range r.Answer {
        cname, ok := ans.(*dns.CNAME)
        if ok {
            lastCname = cname.Target
        }
    }
    return lastCname, nil
}

type LastCnameStub map[string]string

func (m LastCnameStub) LastCname(domain string) (string, error) {
    return m[domain], nil
}

func main() {
    m := make(map[string]string)
    m["www.linkedin.com."] = "pop-tmu1-alpha.www.linkedin.com."
    var l LastCnamer = LastCnameStub(m)
    cname, _ := l.LastCname("www.linkedin.com.")
    fmt.Println("Stub", cname)

    l = LastCnameResolver("8.8.8.8:53")
    cname, err := l.LastCname("www.linkedin.com.")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Resolved", cname)
}
```

Or you make the DNS IP in question configurable so it can be exchanged in testing and start a local DNS server (there's a server in the `github.com/miekg/dns` package), but that would be some more code including selecting a random free port and using that in the tests.